# Accelerometer sensor's data analysis

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency, continuous-signals

Here is a sample data that I got from the accelerometer sensor:

[image]

The first selected area shows the acceleration of the IMU device to right side and the second shows the movement to left side.

I am looking for an algorithm to detect selected areas (as an array of floats) and provide the direction.

I almost don't know anything in this area (signal processing), So I tried to avoid using incorrect keywords, feel free to edit this post.

Answer (score 1):

First, learn about digital differentiators and how to implement them with software. Then apply your accelerometer output signal to a digital differentiator. Next, use software to detect a large positive-valued sample followed by a large negative-valued sample in the differentiator's output sequence. That sample will correspond to your "first selected area". Finally, use software to detect a large negative-valued sample followed by a large positive-valued sample in the differentiator's output sequence. That sample will correspond to your "second selected area".